# Convert GMT time local time in XSLT

Tags: xslt, time, gmt, mdt

How to convert GMT time to local time ( MDT or MST ) automatically.

I got this below working but i need a condition which determines utc -6 or utc -7 based on dates.

`<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime($docdate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT7H')"/>`

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at the function `adjust-time-to-timezone($arg as xs:time?)`, which adjusts the time given in $arg to the implicit timezone given in the dynamic context.  There are no guarantees, but in many implementations that is likely to be the timezone set in the operating system environment.

For example, if I evaluate the expression

```
adjust-time-to-timezone( xs:time('20:45:00.0+01:00'))
```

my system (current set to 7 hours west of UTC) returns the value

```
12:45:00-07:00
```

Comment: It worked fine from stylus studio. But when i used in sap ..i couldn't compile the xsl and got the error saying "Error has occurred during XSL transformation Could not compile stylesheet" [link]http://temp-share.com/show/f3Yg9O92n [link]http://temp-share.com/show/3YgFpWkRx has xml and xslt files.

Comment: Any idea on what could be the problem?

Comment: Your XSLT stylesheet says it's a version 1.0 stylesheet, but the adjust-dateTime-to-timezone and xs:dateTime functions are 2.0 functions.  If the XSLT engine you're using in SAP supports 2.0, try changing the version attribute on the stylesheet element.  But 2.0 processors typically handle this kind of thing without blowing up, so your system may be trying to tell you, in its way, that it cannot handle 2.0 functions.

Comment: Thanks C.M. , That's what i thought..but wanted expert opinion. So,what is the way left for me to do that date manipulation in XSLT 1.0 ?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have much in the way of environment queries, but if your processor supports the EXSLT date-time functions you might be able to use [exslt:date-time()](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/index.html) to determine your operating system's current offset from UTC.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a script, for example a javascript using [javascript dates](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference).

Comment: So, are you saying i can write JS in XSL? if yes,would you provide me an example?

Comment: A first example that I found is http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?20815-Using-Javascript-in-XSL

Comment: would only work in an xslt engine that supported javascript, presumably in a browser or javascript already.